# Mysql Selection

Tags: php, mysql

Hi good people once again

While busy traversing, iterating and manipulating my arrays from a mysql database i have stumbled on a problem, which i know you will be able to help me with - fellow geeks.

I have a COLUMN the contains city names and some cities appear several times on the COLUMN.

I'm using the following query to retrieve that data:

```
  $query = "SELECT cities from info_table WHERE store='kfc' ";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

while($city = mysql_fetch_array($result){
$total_cities_array[]=$city[0];
}
```

the problem is that in $total_cities_array some cities are a entered several when i ony need a single storage for every city.
is there some php or mysql that i can use to fix this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT cities from info_table WHERE store='kfc' GROUP BY cities";
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cities from info_table WHERE store='kfc'
```